# Transfering files from QGIS to ArcGIS, wrong topology and fantoms objects

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, shapefile

I am working in a project with both QGis and ArcGIS. I do mostly cosmetic work and digitalize with QGIS then transfer the shapefiles on ArcGIS. At work I am the only one to work on QGIS, the other members have ArcGIS, (not our choice, question of tight budget). This also mean I have no support, no one is familiar with the program.

This worked fine as long as I was only transfering ready files to ArcGIS, but lately I worked for a short time on the files in ArcGIS (I projected the files and edited) and eventually I had to take back the files from ArcGIS and edit further with QGIS.

When I send back those files in ArcGIS they are messed up.

The edited shapefiles are right on QGIS (topology fine, TOC fine), but on ArcGIS I have "fantoms" polygons or objects (without any geometry) AND overlapping polygons: the old version of the edited polygon/object plus the new polygon/object.

Though I have a column with unique IDs to help sort that out, some of the fantoms/old polygons get a "0" for ID some other the same ID as the original polygon.

So I delete the mistakes in ArcGIS, the file is fine according to ArcGIS. I double check on QGIS, and surprise, I am now missing polygons there!

This is becoming a big mess, and I am unable to understand where are my mistakes coming from so I can avoid them in the future.

I also have problems with special signs (Swedish signs, ö, ä, å) translating in other signs or letters from on program to the other. I have made some reference excel table to join to the gibberish TOC, but when constantly editing, it is complicated to keep track of the newest version. Any other solution is welcome!

Comment: Thanks user30184 for the quick answer!
I work on QGIS 2.10.1 this would explain where this bug comes from. I will try again and let you know if "Save as"  solves the problem!